# Почему метод не выходит из цикла?

Tags: java, android, zip

Я принимаю с сервера `zip` директорию с этим проблем нет, но следующий шаг мне нужно ее распаковать делаю я это с помощью вот этого метода

```
Decompress d = new Decompress(avatarModelZipFile.toString(), getAvatarPath(context).toString());
    d.unzip();
```

вот класс

```
public class Decompress {
private String _zipFile;
private String _location;

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
    _zipFile = zipFile;
    _location = location;
    _dirChecker("");
}

public void unzip() {

    try  {

        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze;
        while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            Log.v("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {

                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());


             for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
---->    Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                    fos.write(c);
                }


                zin.closeEntry();
                fos.close();
            }
        }
        zin.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

}

private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(_location + dir);

    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
}
```

и когда выполнение добегает до цикла

```
for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read())
```

то уже из него не выходит... Я проверил несколько других примеров и в них тоже реализована распаковка `zip` так же... Почему тогда мой цикл никогда не получает значение `c != -1;` ?

Что я делаю не так?

Одна из попыток реализаций

```
private void fff(String path) {

    Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!! 1");

    String SFTPHOST = "host";
    int SFTPPORT = 3232;
    String SFTPUSER = "user";
    String SFTPPASS = "mypass";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/dir/work";
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    try {

        Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!! 2");

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);


        ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(channelSftp.get(path));
        zipStream.getNextEntry();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(zipStream);
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            Log.e("!!!!!!!!!!", "!!!!!!!!!!!! 3");

            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
        if (channelSftp != null) {
            channelSftp.disconnect();
        }
        if (channel != null) {
            channel.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Но получаю такую ошибку

> [CDS][DNS]Unable to resolve host "host": No address associated with hostname
>   06-25 14:10:28.217 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "host": No address associated with hostname
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.serverConnection.GetAvatar.fff(GetAvatar.java:248)
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.serverConnection.GetAvatar.doInBackground(GetAvatar.java:53)
>   06-25 14:10:28.219 17128-17608/com.example.android.camera2basic.demo W/System.err:     at com.example.android.camera2basic.tools.serverConnection.GetAvatar.doInBackground(GetAvatar.java:29)

Comment: Попробуйте так: [тык](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23870501/3212712)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Что то для меня это слишком запутанная реализация... Я добавил зависимость, взял метод как в примере и заменил пару строк как показано в ответе к тому вопросу, но у меня показывает ошибку и я не совсем понимаю, что нужно сделать... И конечно если вы в двух словах опишите как это работает было б круто)) я так понял, что это работает как подключение к серверу через сокет. Сейчас кстати вопрос дополню

Comment: брр, смешались в кучу конелюди, jsch, сканер... Возможно просто побайтовое чтение файла с выводом в лог на каждый байт занимает слишком много времени. Попробуйте прокачать поток через буфер (точно так же, как вы файл из интернета скачиваете)

Comment: @zRrr да вы правы, как раз только что добавил в ответы рабочий вариант... Но блин это у меня получилось методом тыка, я вспомнил, что у меня есть метод который заваричивает зип и по его подобию сделал метод который разворачивает его... Как у вас получается на глаз определить правильное решение?)) Уже 2-й раз вы мне советуете с точностью 100%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге вот так все у меня заработало

```
public class Decompress {
private String _zipFile;
private String location;

public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
    _zipFile = zipFile;
    this.location = location;
    _dirChecker("");
}

public void unzip() {
    try  {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(fin);
        ZipEntry ze;

        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            Log.e("Decompress", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

            if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                _dirChecker(ze.getName());
            } else {
                write(zis, new FileOutputStream(location + ze.getName()));
                zis.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        zis.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e);
    }

}

private void write(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    out.close();
}

private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
    File f = new File(location + dir);
    if(!f.isDirectory()) {
        f.mkdirs();
    }
}
}
```